# Cloning joomla site .htaccess redirection issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a joomla live site (www.site.com) and a working cloned version in subdirectory for translation purposes (www.site.com/en).

When I enter in the translated version for the first time, I am unable to access to the original website. Always I'm redirected to the /en subdirectory, is impossible to access to www.mysite.com

I cloned the website with URL rewrite ON and friendly URL's ON, maybe this can be the problem.

I need to make some modifications to the .htaccess file or something?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend cloning the site to translate it. This is where extensions come in handy ;)

Comment: Typically the `.htaccess` file contains a `RewriteBase` that should have been `/en` for the cloned version but needs to be updated to just `/` for the live version.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to edit/create the .htacces file in the /en sub-directory with a rewrite base without the /en.  Although I strongly recommended using the core language functionality as much as possible.  Not only for your own sanity, but otherwise you'll forever be trying to address endless work arounds!